# List all posts in a category with query_post() function

Tags: categories, query-posts, page-template, get-posts

I'm a `C programmer`, konw little about `PHP`. I built a Blog with wordpress.

Yestoday, I try to create the page `www.abc.com/server`, this page would list all posts which belong to `server` category.

I found some useful information in wordpress document and Google

I created a template like this:

```
<?php
 /*
  * Template name: list_catetory
  */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
    ...
    <?php 
    query_posts( 'cat_name = $pagename' );
    if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post-list"  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h2>
             <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
             ....
        </h2>
     </div>

     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
     ...
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I create a page named `server` with this template.

then I open this page, I found this page list all post.

Why it lists all post, not only list the posts belong to `server` category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The use of `query_posts()`
2. Undefined `$pagename` variable

I assume that you want to use the **page slug** as the string passed for the category parameter in the query arguments array? You can get that via `$post->post_name`, like so:

```
global $post;
$page_slug = $post->post_name;
```

Then, to pass that as a query parameter, you would pass it as `'category_name'`.

Finally, you want to output a custom query, [via **`WP_Query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), rather than call `query_posts()`:

```
// Globalize $post
global $post;
// Custom query args array
$category_query_args = array(
    'category_name' => $post->post_name
);
// Instantiate category query
$category_query = new WP_Query( $category_query_args );
```

Then, you can loop through your custom query like so:

```
// Open category query loop
if ( $category_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $category_query->have_posts() ) : $category_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="post-list"  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h2>
             <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
             ....
        </h2>
     </div>

    <?php
// Close category query loop
endwhile; endif;
// Reset $post data
wp_reset_postdata();
```